# Swiss rail supersaver tickets

Tags: trains, switzerland

Arriving at Geneva airport on a Friday evening by Swissair, and then travelling by train to Aigle.
If the plane is late do the railway inspectors get narked and charge you if the train we take is a different one to the booking?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, supersaver tickets are limited to a specific train ride.

From the [SBB's terms and conditions](https://www.sbb.ch/en/travelcards-and-tickets/buying-options/online/general-terms-and-conditions.html):

> **Supersaver tickets**
>
> Supersaver tickets are electronic tickets that can
>   only be used on certain trains and their prices are correspondingly
>   reduced. Supersaver tickets can only be obtained as electronic
>   tickets. Supersaver tickets are personal and are valid only for the
>   **day, train (train number) and route** printed on the ticket. Booked
>   tickets are not associated with any fixed seat (seat reservation). [...]
>
> **Provisions on refunds.**
>
> If customers with a supersaver ticket **miss their booked connection** or
>   want to travel at another time, they can purchase a ticket at the
>   standard tariff and obtain a refund for the supersaver ticket after
>   the journey. To do this, customers must show both their original
>   supersaver ticket with confirmation from the member of the sales or
>   ticket inspection staff and the original ticket at the standard
>   tariff. Only tickets with completely identical routes can be refunded.